# what is spec_path for fastlane action appium?

Tags: ios, rspec, appium, ui-automation, fastlane

I'm trying to use appium using fastlane. What exactly is spec_path?

From documentation: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/#appium

> Path to Appium spec directory

```
appium(
  app_path:  "appium/apps/TargetApp.app",
  spec_path: "appium/spec",
  platform:  "iOS",
  caps: {
    versionNumber: "9.1",
    deviceName:    "iPhone 6"
  }
)
```

Comment: I know it's an old question, but did you find any solution back then? I'm stuck with this spec_path and don't find anything about what value I should use.

Comment: i dropped it. Not a good tool. Stick to native xctests

Answer (score 1):

According to the [description in *fastlane*](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/a32c0c15985196a88459c8b58c1d73179ddb596b/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/appium.rb#L102), the Appium action allows you to, "Run UI test by Appium with RSpec". `spec_path` refers to a file path (usually ending in a directory called `spec`) in which [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) will find the tests to run.

The article, [Automated iOS and Android Acceptance Testing with RSpec and Appium](https://saucelabs.com/blog/automated-ios-and-android-acceptance-testing-with-rspec-and-appium) may be a good introduction to the pieces of the puzzle.